# How to obtain native logger in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, logging, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Is it possible to obtain the logger somehow that Selenium WebDriver uses? I want to capture a transcript of all the commands that were issued (eg: open, wait, click, etc). In particular I am looking for a java solution, as I am exporting the tests into junit.

I found this code on their website, however it displays nothing on standard out

```
    DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.firefox(); 
    LoggingPreferences logs = new LoggingPreferences(); 
    logs.enable(LogType.DRIVER, Level.FINEST); 
    caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logs); 
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(caps);
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Enable logging in the driver you're using, select which log types you're interested in and the log level (I'm using FirefoxDriver, enabling all types of logs and collecting all log messages)

```
LoggingPreferences logs = new LoggingPreferences();
logs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);
logs.enable(LogType.CLIENT, Level.ALL);
logs.enable(LogType.DRIVER, Level.ALL);
logs.enable(LogType.PERFORMANCE, Level.ALL);
logs.enable(LogType.PROFILER, Level.ALL);
logs.enable(LogType.SERVER, Level.ALL);

DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
desiredCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logs);

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(desiredCapabilities);
```

Then, after running the test you can collect the logs (I'm only collecting the DRIVER logs, but you can do the same for any type of log)

```
Logs logs = driver.manage().logs();
LogEntries logEntries = logs.get(LogType.DRIVER);

for (LogEntry logEntry : logEntries) {
    System.out.println(logEntry.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: How would I capture that logs with log4j or any other logger?

Comment: @MichelFeldheim Instead of printing "logEntry.getMessage()" to the console in the example above, you should print that value using log4j logger.

Comment: nice solution for FF but have you a solution for IE11?

Comment: I wrote this a long time ago, but my best guess would still be that you need to change the driver. In my example I use `FirefoxDriver`, which you could in principle replace by any other driver, namely a driver for IE11. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
driver.manage().logs()
```

You will get Logs interface that has methods to get logs and log types. See [Logs interface docs](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/logging/Logs.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using log4j for logging as utils logger is the most easiest and straight forward one that, that can be used (IMHO).

POM dependencies:

```
<dependency>
          <groupId> org.apache.cassandra</groupId>
          <artifactId>cassandra-all</artifactId>
          <version>0.8.1</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
          <version>1.6.6</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
          <version>1.6.6</version>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
          <version>1.6.6</version>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
          <version>1.6.6</version>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
      </dependency>
```

imports are following:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
```

usage:

```
private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(classname.class);
```

and then just use it as such:

```
logger.info ("butonCLick");
driver.findElement(By.id("blablabla")).click();
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: You are manually logging with `logger.info ("butonCLick");`. I am doing that now too, but it is a pain and also unreliable. I want to obtain a native selenium logger and do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename = log_filename, level = logging.DEBUG)
```

Reference - [Selenium unit tests in Python -- where is my log file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999581/selenium-unit-tests-in-python-where-is-my-log-file)