# Selenium unit tests in Python -- where is my log file?

Tags: python, logging, selenium

So I exported some unit tests from the Selenium IDE to Python.  Now I'm trying to debug something, and I've noticed that Selenium uses the `logging` module.  There is one particular line in `selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection` that I would really like to see the output of.  It is:

```
LOGGER.debug('%s %s %s' % (method, url, data))
```

At the top of the file is another line that reads:

```
LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

So where is this log file?  I want to look at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your unit test script, place

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename = log_filename, level = logging.DEBUG)
```

where `log_filename` is a path to wherever you'd like the log file written to.

Without the call to `logging.basicConfig` or some such call to setup a logging handler, the `LOGGER.debug` command does nothing.