# Logging Testcase Flow Using python and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, logging

I am automating the test Using python and selenium i want to log the test flow . Any suggested plugins or methods to logging ?

Comment: You can use the module `logging` from python and set a path wherever you'd like the log file written to.

Comment: ok .it will log the flow of the test-case? @PetIbaño

Comment: Manually, yes. Try this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/20112491/7265539

Comment: There are two answers there actually. Feel free to choose what suits you.

Comment: Read this too for setting your log file path http://stackoverflow.com/a/13999647/7265539

Comment: For more info, take this reference https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html