# Selenium - How to log every step that is being performed?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I'm trying to find a way to log every action performed by the `selenium driver` object. `Log4j` is the commonly suggested solution. However, dedicated log statements are needed to add to the log as below -

```
driver.findElement(By.name("opt1")).sendKeys("km");
log.debug("selecting distance unit");
driver.findElement(By.name("opt2")).sendKeys("10");
log.debug("selecting distance value");
```

So i have to have log statements wherever i need to log. Is there anything which tracks the actions of the selenium driver and gives a general log?

Comment: The native logs is what i'm looking for exactly. I searched a lot but couldn't find a related post. Thank you.

Comment: Better go with `Testng` or `JUnit`

Answer (score 2):

Extend the WebDriver class you are using and override the log function, this function gets called before and after each function call.

Example:

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionId;

public class MyWebDriver extends ChromeDriver {
    @Override
    protected void log(SessionId sessionId, String commandName, Object toLog, When when) {
        System.out.println("LOG: sessionId: " + sessionId + " when: " + when + " commandName: " + commandName + " toLog: " + toLog);
        super.log(sessionId, commandName, toLog, when);
    }
}
```

This code will give you output that look like this:

```
LOG: sessionId: 70521460-9ccf-4619-97ea-e7be4717a9b8 when: BEFORE commandName: findElement toLog: [70521460-9ccf-4619-97ea-e7be4717a9b8, findElement {using=xpath, value=//*[@hint='Username']}]
LOG: sessionId: 70521460-9ccf-4619-97ea-e7be4717a9b8 when: AFTER commandName: findElement toLog: [70521460-9ccf-4619-97ea-e7be4717a9b8, findElement {using=xpath, value=//*[@hint='Username']}]
LOG: sessionId: 70521460-9ccf-4619-97ea-e7be4717a9b8 when: BEFORE commandName: findElement toLog: [70521460-9ccf-4619-97ea-e7be4717a9b8, findElement {using=xpath, value=//*[@id='Password']}]
LOG: sessionId: 70521460-9ccf-4619-97ea-e7be4717a9b8 when: AFTER commandName: findElement toLog: [70521460-9ccf-4619-97ea-e7be4717a9b8, findElement {using=xpath, value=//*[@id='Password']}]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are planning to use selenium server observe the nodes terminal once execution starts, it logs each and every step in much detailed fashion. [browserstack](https://www.browserstack.com/) uses this technique I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium has its own log system, you should import `LoggingPreferences` and do as below

```
LoggingPreferences logs = new LoggingPreferences();
logs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);
```

there are different `LogType` like `PERFORMANCE, SERVER, DRIVER, ....` which you can enable, disable or set level for it. for more info take a look at the answer in the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204820/how-to-obtain-native-logger-in-selenium-webdriver)