# Selenium IEDriverServer logging

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver

I have the below code which will set the property for webdriver before starting the IE Driver. My intent is to capture the info,fatal and error logs.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\IEDriverServer.exe");            
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver.loglevel","FATAL");     
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver.loglevel","INFO");      
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver.loglevel","ERROR");     
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver.logfile","C:\\IEServerlog.log");
```

But this code generates only for the last loglevel. Means the log level set at final step.
Here it is ERROR.

I need to generate the log for all the levels. What should be the approach?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to obtain native logger in Selenium WebDriver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204820/how-to-obtain-native-logger-in-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the IE loglevel is like log4j in that the loglevel will include all log levels "beneath" it.  EG:  ERROR will include ERROR and FATAL messages.   INFO will include INFO, WARN, ERROR and FATAL messages.

So set `ie.driver.loglevel` at the lowest level of logging you want; which in the original post would be `INFO`