# Better Reporting with Maven Framework for Selenium WebDriver

Tags: maven, xslt, selenium-webdriver, reporting

I have gone thru multiple posts available for reporting with maven. I'm trying to figure out ways to generate a clear report which has performance data, results and browser details and a good representation of the summary. So far, I've not been able to find out any posts which are helpful. If someone can point me to a way to generate reports just like XSLT format, that would be awesome.

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you,
NickJS

Answer (score 0):

There is no straightforward solution as far as I'm concerned, however you may find following helpful:
If you're not using any testing framework you may collect reports from surefire as described in here: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/usage.html
Also, you may want to report browsers related info using WebDriver's logs as described in here:
[How to obtain native logger in Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204820/how-to-obtain-native-logger-in-selenium-webdriver)

If you're using testing frameworks there is a little more you can get out of them, for example using testNG you may add listeners to your tests and report everything as html using following reporters:
http://reportng.uncommons.org/
OR
http://extentreports.com/

If you consider using BDD approach there is a nice Cucumber Json reporter for Jenkins, also available as maven dependency:
https://github.com/jenkinsci/cucumber-reports-plugin

Hope you'll find this helpful.

Comment: Thank you! This is informative. I've started using Extent Reporting. That seems to work.