# How to get full page screenshot of my web application?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am testing my web application using selenium, I am able to take screenshot but it only captures the area visible on screen (doesn’t scroll the page)

My requirement is to get the screenshot of entire page.

I am using code to capture screenshot is:

```
var ss = driver.GetScreenshot();
ss.SaveAsFile("ss.png",System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

Comment: Would you consider to accept a solution in Java?

Answer (score 0):

There is a package called [Noksa.WebDriver.ScreenshotsExtensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Noksa.WebDriver.ScreenshotsExtensions/0.0.4.4) try it!

You can use `VerticalCombineDecorator` like this:

```
var verticalscreenshot = new VerticalCombineDecorator(new ScreenshotMaker());
var screen = driver.TakeScreenshot(verticalscreenshot);
```

You can look up [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52063597/8179099) answer...

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer for which might help others. Below is the function which will take a full page screenshot and save it to the desired location.

```
public void TakeFullScreenshot(IWebDriver driver, String filename)
{
    Screenshot screenshot = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();
    screenshot.SaveAsFile(filename, ImageFormat.Png);
}
```